# ads are killing my page speed

Tags: advertising, page-speed

What are others doing to mitigate the horror that is the slow speed of running ads on their sites?

I don't do direct sales of ads & rely on third parties like rubicon, openx, etc. served through Google DFP which are so slow I want to shoot my browser.

Any and all suggestions welcome!

Notice
- I already load the ads through google DPF
- I'm putting ad loading to the last things run

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [Google Publisher Tag](http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181073). It allows asynchronous single-request ad delivery, meaning your page won't block while ads are loaded.

There are some trade-offs - your ad inventory must work within iframes (ie. no expandable units), but if you can work with that constraint it should solve your problem.

Comment: that doesn't solve the overall speed issue though.

Comment: Are you sure? An asynchronous iframe solution should prevent slow third-party ad delivery from impacting your page speed.

Comment: Well I think so... in my context I'm measuring the entire page speed a la webpagetest.org which in its entirety is how google measures as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Adzerk](http://adzerk.com) - we use all asynchronous tags to make sure your page loads as fast as possible. (we are used by StackExchange for this very reason)

**disclaimer - I run Adzerk.

Comment: problem remains, the overall sitespeed is still the same despite shuffling the load order.